# Which is the best way in Javascript to set instances of an object as function parameters

Tags: javascript, function, callback, arguments

excuse me if the question is stupid but I need to ask.

I start using callback functions a while ago and I want to know if I am doing it the best way.

What I am doing at the moment is something like this:

```
function foo(someArg, callbackFunc, callbackArg1, callbackArg1, callbackArg3, .. callbackArgN);
```

What I want to achieve in order to make my code clearer and easier to maintain is :

```
callBackArgs= {
 0: callbackArg1, 
 1: callbackArg1, 
 2: callbackArg3,
 .
 . 
 N: callbackArgN
}
```

I would like to execute the foo() like this :

```
function foo(someArg, callbackFunc, callBackArgs)
```

Then inside the foo function I would like to manipulate the callBackArgs in a way that I could use them as arguments of the callbackFunc.

PS. The length of the object is not always the same .

Comment: Try using Spread syntax if you are on ES6 - Moe info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: Why would you need to pass all of a callback's arguments to the function that calls it?

Comment: Yeah, passing the arguments you're going to pass to the callback sounds very weird and should not be necessary. A callback can "carry" its own arguments if it needs to, and your `foo` would just pass additional arguments to the callback if it wants to. `foo` should not have to worry or know about extra arguments to `callbackFunc` which don't originate from `foo` itself.

Comment: OK, well with that context...I still don't think you need to pass all the arguments. What I was getting at with my question is that there's probably a better way to structure the code so that you don't need to pass all those values around.

Comment: @nnnnnn Long story short. I created a ajaxPost function that handles form posting and validation. 
So this function has 3 functionalities:
1. checks if the form is valid. That means that the object I am posting has an instance 'validate' (at least this is my case). 2. When the data are checked this 'validate' instance is being deleted and then I am calling the same ajaxPost function inside the ajaxPost function, but this time the second functionality of this function is being triggered coz validate is already done. So this time a normal post is happening .
Functionality no3 is irrelevant.

Comment: @nnnnnn maybe I should take a step back and rethink the code structure indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't typically do this at all… It sounds like you're asking for this:

```
function foo(callback, callbackArgs) {
    callback.apply(null, callbackArgs);
}

foo(bar, ['baz', 42]);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply.

However, this places the responsibility of caring about the callback arguments on `foo`, which just makes the whole implementation more complicated. The callback should care about its own arguments instead:

```
function foo(callback) {
    callback();
}

foo(function () { bar('baz', 42); });
// or
foo(bar.bind(null, 'baz', 42));
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an array for `callBackArgs`.

Then when you want to call `callbackFunc` use: `callbackFunc.apply(this, callBackArgs`.

That's similar to calling `callbackFunc(callbackArgs[0], ... callbackArgs[n])`

Answer (score 0):

```
function callbackFunc(){
  console.log('callback called');
}

foo.apply(this, ['someArg', callbackFunc, 1,2,3,4]);
```

You can call it using JavaScript's apply function, giving all the arguments as an array. 1,2,3,4 are you callback arguments in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `arguments` object which will gives you all the parameters. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Define your function as following:

```
function foo () {
    console.log(arguments) // [someArg, callbackFunc, callbackArg1, callbackArg1, callbackArg3, .. ,callbackArgN]
}
```

call you functions simply by `foo(someArg, callbackFunc, callbackArg1, callbackArg1, callbackArg3, .. ,callbackArgN)`

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you're trying to do is good! Follow the same approach if you want to manipulate the arguments in other function.

Using **`callBackArgs`** as object makes you easy to find the argument and manipulate accordingly.

Try to have a temporary array **`(tempArray)`** and push all the arguments into it after manipulation and call the

```
  callbackFn.apply(this, tempArray)
```

when you need.